# What select the keywords from others?

Tags: python-3.6

`import` is a keyword while `input` is a builtin function

```
In [48]: import keyword
In [54]: keyword.iskeyword('import')
Out[54]: True
In [57]: keyword.iskeyword('input')
Out[57]: False
In [55]: type(input)
Out[55]: builtin_function_or_method
```

What's the rule to select the current 33 keywords from others(builtins)?

Comment: A keyword is part of the language's grammar, it's not a function, class, object or whatever.

Comment: Keywords need special processing in parser in addition to normal (e.g. expression) parsing (which is enough for builtin functions, classes, ...)